# How to remove all traces of a single file in git

Tags: git

I recently noticed that I had a file with sensitive information under version control in git. I have now added this file to my .gitignore list, but how can I remove all mention of it from my commit history without touching anything else? i.e., I don't want to just delete my `.git` directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this guide on the GitHub help site: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Specifically:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: Will this remove any trace of the sensitive file in `.git/` folder metadata?.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. This [github remove-sensitive-data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) and this [remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history) explain it.